# how to insert new row in 1st position with single quotes with awk

Tags: awk

I got very limited knowledge with awk.
I got big csv files (500.000 lines) with following lines format:

```
'0000011197118123','136',,'35993706', '33745', '22052', 'appsflyer.com'  
'0000011194967123','136',,'35282806', '74518', '30317', 'crashlytics.com'  
'0000011199022123’,’139',,'01363100', '8776250', '373671', 'whatsapp.com'  
............
```

I need to cut first 8 digit from first column and add date field, as a new first  column, (date should be the day-1 date) like following:

```
'2016/03/12','97118123','136',,'35993706','33745','22052','appsflyer.com'  
'2016/03/12','94967123','136',,'35282806','74518','30317','crashlytics.com'  
'2016/03/12','99022123’,’139',,'01363100','8776250','373671','whatsapp.com'
```

Thanks a lot for your time.
M.Tave

Comment: Please post, what have you tried so far??

Comment: Is the `00000111` part of the first field relevant? What does 'date should be the day-1 date' mean?

Comment: @Raju tried *sed ’s/00000965//g’ infile.csv > outfile.csv* to eliminate first 8 chars from first column and then *awk -F, '{$1=‘2016’ FS $1;}1' OFS=, infile.csv > outfile.csv* to add new firs column but not able to add single quotes.

Comment: @dawg **00000111** is not relevant. With date-1 I wanted to add the date of day before, but a string is also fine. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -v d='2016/03/12' '{print "\047" d "\047,\047" substr($0,10)}' file
'2016/03/12','97118123','136',,'35993706', '33745', '22052', 'appsflyer.com'
'2016/03/12','94967123','136',,'35282806', '74518', '30317', 'crashlytics.com'
'2016/03/12','99022123’,’139',,'01363100', '8776250', '373671', 'whatsapp.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar to:

```
awk -F, -v date="2016/03/12" 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}
             {sub(/^.{8}/, "'\''", $1)
             s="'\''"date"'\''"
             $1=s OFS $1
             print }' csv_file
```

I did not understand how you a determining your date, so i just used a string.

---

Based on comments, you can do:

```
awk -v d="2016/03/12" 'sub(/^.{8}/,"'\''"d"'\'','\''")' csv_file
```

Comment: you can just set `$1 = s FS $1` and leave the other fields alone.

Comment: @karakfa: Edit made. Thanks!

Comment: also, why not `date="'2016/03/12'"`; drop $1 from sub since you already have caret; you can shorten to whole thing to  `awk -v d=".." 'sub(/^.{8}/,d FS)'`